# I want a feature that when user long presses the text in the textView a pop up appear with the definition of that text

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, textview

with **android:textIsSelectable="true"** i have only copy and share functionality by the system but i want to have a **pop up** with that word definition

In addition, it would be great if i can **highlight** that selected word

Comment: **Use following library**: https://github.com/ECLaboratorio/BubbleShowCase-Android     ------    
                   
**Another** : https://github.com/skydoves/Balloon

Comment: how can i show that selected text in that bubble?

Comment: You can set the selected text in its title using attribute as :
`.title("foo")` //Any title for the bubble view

Comment: yeah!! but, to state my question more clearly, i am asking  how can i get that selected text from textView like - if user have selected "elephant" then how can i get that elephant word from that textView

Comment: can you plaease share your ui SS

Answer (score 0):

You can use the popup window with the context menu. That suits your requirement perfectly
I could suggest you https://programmersought.com/article/5691145305/ or
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/popup-menu-in-android-with-example/

Change it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

U CAN USE THIS CODE

```
 button.setOnLongClickListener {
 Snackbar.make(root_layout, "Long click", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show()
true
}
```

in addition to it u can give a custom dialog, toast msg as well**strong text**